# PhoneGap (cordovo- 2.7.0) Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        playAudio("songs/abc.mp3'");
    }

    // Audio player
    //
    var my_media = null;
    var mediaTimer = null;

    // Play audio
    //
    function playAudio(src) {
        // Create Media object from 
        my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError,onCallBack);

        // Play audio
        my_media.play();

        // Update my_media position every second
        if (mediaTimer == null) {
            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                // get my_media position
                my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                    // success callback
                    function(position) {
                        if (position > -1) {
                            setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                        }
                    },
                    // error callback
                    function(e) {
                        console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    // Pause audio
    // 
    function pauseAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.pause();
        }
    }

    // Stop audio
    // 
    function stopAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.stop();
        }
        clearInterval(mediaTimer);
        mediaTimer = null;
    }

    // onSuccess Callback
    //
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }


    // onError Callback 
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    // Set audio position
    // 
    function setAudioPosition(position) {
        document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
    }

    </script>
```

I have added the above code.... after device ready function when i click the Play button it shows me Media is not define error....what i suppose to do...is there any configurational problem...or something else...i am new in Phonegap..please guide me .

thanks,

IK

Comment: can you guarantee phonegap is loaded? Is the deviceready() function fired? I assume it´s not the case because Media is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

try using 'android_asset/www/songs/abc.mp3' as src. It worked fine with me.